# Joomla v1.6 - How & Where to set Custom Success Messages in Controller?

Tags: joomla, components, message, contact-form, joomla1.6

In Joomla! 1.6 Contact Form submission, I want to set a custom successful message, so that the front-end user can view that message after he submits the contact form.

There are 2 problems basically:-

1. I am using the default Contact Form component (`com_contact`), as provided by the Joomla! v1.6. But I am unable to find the proper area from where the contact form is submitted & the mail is being sent. So I need to know the page name & the method name of this component, firing the mail from the front-end.
2. How to set the custom messages (just like in the administrator panel) in the particular method of contact form component, to let the front-end user know that he has been able to successfully send the mail to the concerned staff?

Thanks in advance to all who can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To show Message

use `$this->setMessage(JText::_('COM_YOURCOMPONENT_MESSAGE'));` if you are in controller.

or use

```
JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage(JText::_('COM_YOURCOMPONENT_MESSAGE'));
```

And Email is sent through `JoomlaRoot / components / com_contact / controllers / contact.php`

find the function `submit()`, the mailing code is written here.

Comment: Currently, the function which the Joomla! v1.6 is using after the submission of the Contact Us form is the "`display()`" (defined in the "`JoomlaRoot/libraries/joomla/application/component/controller.php` page or the "`JController`" class) & not the "`submit()`". In the tasks, I could see the "`__default`" mentioned as "`display`" & not "`submit`". So the function called is "`display()`". Can you please suggest how to change this behavior?

Comment: Extremely sorry for the last comment, as I have found the structure from where the default task is set. Actually, for testing purposes, I have renamed earlier that task in the form to "`contact.submit123`". So by default, Joomla! was taking "`display`" as its task. Now I've got it straight. Thanks a lot.